# Hash from route to action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i.e. if the following is in the routes.rb

```
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#_help'
```

what is the globally available hash that if given '/help' will return 'static_pages#_help'
or ('static_pages/_help').

been googling "rails routes action match hash" for  45 minutes without sucess.

---

also that would work with

```
root :to => 'static_pages#home_js'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```